# Moment.js Date Formatting

Tags: momentjs

I want to convert the following date from **HTML** input :**`""2018-09-10" to 10 September 2018`**

How can I do that with **momentjs**?

Closest I got is **`alert(moment("10-09-2018", "DD-MM-YYYY"));`** But it returns the time too.

Comment: Please try this code. alert(moment("10-09-2018").format('MMMM Do YYYY')); You can set other format please follow this link: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

To meet your needs use the following code:

```js
const date = moment("10-09-2018", 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('D MMMM YYYY');

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

see more information about formatting [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)